# Regular expression exclude some words but match to one

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Is it possible to write a regex which is matching to "findme" but doesn't match if the line contains "black" or "red" or "yellow" words?

```
Possible regex: (?!black|red|yellow)findme
```

excluded words:  yellow , black  ,  red

Test lines:

```
findme     (OK)
xyz        (NOT!)
XYZfindmeXYZ     (OK)
somethingelseFINDMEsome_thingelse     (OK)
BLACK_ findme       (NOT !)
BLACK findme       (NOT !)
XyBlacK findme xyz_xy       (NOT !)
xy findme RED           (NOT !)
yellow__ findme _xy        (NOT !)
_xy_ findme _something    (OK)
```

Comment: In what context?  What language are you working with?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

`^(?!.*(?:black|red|yellow)).*(findme)`

Demo: https://regexr.com/42r4q

---

**Details:**

- `^` - matches start of the string
- `(?!)` - negative lookahead
- `.*` - Match any character (except newlines) 0+ times
- `(?:)` - non-capturing group
- `black|red|yellow` - matches 'black', 'red' or 'yellow'
- `findme` - matches 'findme' string

**Flags:**

- `g` - global
- `i` - case-insensitive
- `m` - multiline

Comment: You don’t need the trailing look ahead. The first look ahead covers the entire input.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead, anchored to start, for the unwanted terms:

```
^(?i)(?!.*(black|red|yellow)).*findme
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/gC6qrp1NJR) passing all your tests.

`(?i)` means “ignore case"
`(?!...)` is a negative look ahead (asserts without consuming that the expression is not found)